# Client side duplicate data validation in angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I'm trying to figure out if it is possible to validate data client side to ensure that no duplicates are sent to the database. I have an angular app which gets data from an api call. This is my current controller for adding a new subject (functioning perfectly, but without data validation):

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('SubjectNewCtrl', ['$scope', 'SubjectsFactory', '$location', '$route',
    function ($scope, SubjectsFactory, $location, $route) {

        // callback for ng-click 'createNewSubject':
        $scope.createNewSubject = function () {
            SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects);
            $location.path('/subjects');

        }

    }]);
```

And here is what I have been attempting for data validation:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('SubjectNewCtrl', ['$scope', 'SubjectsFactory', '$location', '$route',
    function ($scope, SubjectsFactory, $location, $route) {

        // callback for ng-click 'createNewUser':
        $scope.createNewSubject = function () {

            var newSubject = $scope.subject.name;
            var someSubject = $scope.subjects;
            var oldSubject;

            if(newSubject){
                angular.forEach($scope.subjects, function(allSubjects){
                    if(newSubject.toLowerCase() == allSubjects.name.toLowerCase()){
                        oldSubject = true;
                    }
                });
                if (!oldSubject){
                   SubjectsFactory.create($scope.subjects); 
                }
            }
        }

    }]);
```

This gives me a console error- `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`. How do I access the 'name' property of my new subject from the html? Can anyone tell me if what I am trying to do is possible/ makes sense?

Comment: Can you share a plunker? It's hard to understand how this is all hooked up. The error means "$scope.subject is undefined", is $scope.subject the subject to be added?

Comment: Yes, it is the object to be added. I don't know if that makes sense. I will try get a plunker working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you should use a directive for the specific field you are trying to validate.  A unique email directive would be a common example.  Here is one I have used in the past.  Nothing fancy.

```
MyApp.directive('uniqueEmail', ['$http', function($http) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
            //set the initial value as soon as the input comes into focus
            element.on('focus', function() {
                if (!scope.initialValue) {
                    scope.initialValue = ctrl.$viewValue;
                }
            });
            element.on('blur', function() {
                if (ctrl.$viewValue != scope.initialValue) {
                    var dataUrl = attrs.url + "?email=" + ctrl.$viewValue;
                    //you could also inject and use your 'Factory' to make call
                    $http.get(dataUrl).success(function(data) {
                        ctrl.$setValidity('isunique', data.result);
                    }).error(function(data, status) {
                        //handle server error
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

Then in your markup you could use it like so.

```
<input type="text" name="email" ng-model="item.email" data-unique-email="" data-url="/api/check-unique-email" />
<span class="validation-error" ng-show="form.email.$error.isunique && form.email.$dirty">Duplicate Email</span>
```

Hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need to do. How would I inject my factory service?

Comment: MyApp.directive('uniqueEmail', ['myFactory', function(myFactory){ ...etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have implemented object creation in Angular js many times.

My createNew button method typically just created a new javascript Object() and set the scope.currentObject to the new Object();

In your case it appears that $scope.subject is not initialized to anything, hence the error.

I guess that there must be a html input on your form that is bound the subject.name field but without a subject Object to hold the name it is effectively unbound.

If I wanted users to enter a name then click create button to validate that the name is not used.  I would bind the new Name input to a different $scope variable (perhaps $scope.newName)

Then in the createNewSubject method you can actually create a new subject like this:

```
  $scope.subject = new Object();
  $scope.subject.name = $scope.newName;
```

Then you can run your validation code.